# WPF DataGrid Save Column Width

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to Save and Restore `DataGrid` columns width, I tried this:

```
private void dataGrid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in dataGrid.Columns.GetEnumeratorWithIndex())
    {
        Settings.ColumnWidth[item.Index] =
            new DataGridLength(item.Value.Width.Value,
            DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel,
            item.Value.Width.DesiredValue, item.Value.Width.DisplayValue);
    }
}
```

Restore:

```
foreach (var item in dataGrid.Columns.GetEnumeratorWithIndex())
{
    item.Value.Width = new
        DataGridLength(Settings.ColumnWidth[item.Index].Value,
        DataGridLengthUnitType.Pixel,
        Settings.ColumnWidth[item.Index].DesiredValue,
        Settings.ColumnWidth[item.Index].DisplayValue);
}
```

But not working and all columns stored as Auto.

Update:

[image: Update]

Comment: What is it failing, the storing, the loading or the final width modification? Why does it fail, is it ignoring you or is it modifying the width unexpectedly (like in a different order)? May you have a datagrid configuration parameter  that prevents from modifying manually the column width? Sometimes it is not the column width what you have to modify but the column **Header** width, I'm not sure right now

Comment: @AmoRobb all columns are saved as Auto, but If I use Debug.WriteLine(item.Value.Width.Value), I can see that the values are different and in numbers

Comment: if solution from [EldHasp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67080153/10109389) still doesn't work, please provide some more info about the discrepancies you are experiencing

Comment: @AmoRobb i updated my question you can see that all values are saved as Auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the property `ActualWidth`:

```
for (int index = 0; index < dataGrid.Columns.Count; index++)
    Settings.ColumnWidth[index] = new
        DataGridLength(dataGrid.Columns[index].ActualWidth);
```

Example of reading column sizes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void GetWidthsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join("; ",
            dataGrid.Columns.Select(column => column.Width))
            + Environment.NewLine + string.Join("; ",
            dataGrid.Columns.Select(column => column.ActualWidth)));
    }
}
public class TextsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Texts> Rows { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<Texts>()
    {
        new Texts() {Text1="123", Text2="45678",
            Text3="90qwer", Text4="tyuiio", Text5="as"},
        new Texts() {Text1="asad", Text2="gfg",
            Text3="hkjhk", Text4="kl", Text5="fgfhgf"}
    };
}
public class Texts
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }
    public string Text4 { get; set; }
    public string Text5 { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid DataContext="{DynamicResource viewModel}">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <local:TextsViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Get Widths" Grid.Row="1"
            Click="GetWidthsClick"
            Margin="5" Padding="15 5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks but not worked and All values are saved as Auto (i updated my question you can see result)

Comment: You are doing something wrong.
I supplemented the answer with a larger example.
It reads the Width and ActualWidth values.
And you can see that Width for all Auto, and ActualWidth contains the real width.

Comment: Please note that only ONE parameter should be passed to the DataGridLength constructor.
And this parameter is ActualWidth, not Width.

Comment: There is also a possibility that you have a mistake somewhere else.
Place a breakpoint after the Settings.ColumnWidth assignment loop and check the stored values.

Comment: in messagebox everything is ok but in setting file all value is Auto, i defined setting variable in this way:  ```public virtual DataGridLength[] ColumnWidth { get; set; } = new DataGridLength[5];``` Is it because of that?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure - more details are needed.
I would advise you to keep just double widths.

Comment: i changed to double, now all values saved as 0.0, mybe my jsonsetting is broked thanks anyway

Comment: The problem is clearly outside the code you showed. Place breakpoints after assigning values, check what they are and where they subsequently change to defaut.
You are most likely confused with instances of Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary width the columns properties, and restore them when you need:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<int, DataGridLength> columnsWidth = new Dictionary<int, DataGridLength>(); 
    //Dictionary<int, GridViewLength> columnsWidth = new Dictionary<int, GridViewLength>(); //telerik
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
           columnsWidth.Add(i, dataGrid.Columns[i].Width);
        }
    }

    private void RestoreColumnsWidth()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
           dataGrid.Columns[i].Width = columnsWidth[i];
        }
    }
 }
```